# How to install Huawei E160 USB modem on Apple Mac OS X Snow Leopard (10.6)

Tags: osx-snow-leopard, modem

My Huawei E160 USB modem worked fine on Apple Mac OS X Leopard (10.5), but it does not work on Snow Leopard (10.6).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This will probably work for other Huawei devices, not only for E160.

- use Windows machine or mobile phone to disable SIM card PIN (will not work if PIN is not disabled)

  - for example, to disable PIN on iPhone (iOS 4.3.3): Settings > Phone > SIM PIN > OFF
- insert SIM card into Huawei device
- plug the device
- when the disk image appears (named `web'n'walk` in my case) open it
- right click on the application (named `T-Mobile web'n'walk` in my case)
- click `Show Package Contents`
- go to `Contents/Resources` and run `Mobile_Connect_Drv_App.pkg` (it crashed this time, I do not remember it crashing on another machine)
- `New network interfaces have been detected` pop up appears saying `DIAG` and `HUAWEI Mobile` network interfaces are not set up

  - if the pop up does not appear, go to `Network Preferences` > `+` > `Interface: HUAWEI Mobile` > `Service Name: HUAWEI Mobile` > `Create`
- click button `Network Preferences` in the pop up
- select `HUAWEI Mobile` in `Network` window
- enter `*99#` in `Telephone Number`
- check `Show modem status in menu bar` (optional)
- click button `Connect`
- click button `Apply` in the warning pop up that appears

Source: [huawei e160 not working in 10.6](http://discussions.apple.com/message.jspa?messageID=10187037)

Answer (score 0):

On Mac OS X 10.7 (and I guess 10.8) my first answer does not work. You have to download [TOOL-DashboardInstaller V100R001B003.zip](http://www.huaweidevice.com/resource/mini/200910149695/testmobile1014/index.html). Unzip the file and you will get `DashboardInstaller.dmg` and `DashboardInstaller user manual.pdf`. Install the `dmg` file following the instructions in the `pdf` file.